# How do I plot a normalized countplot of data across multiple columns

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I have some data of individuals that use a give programming language which is organized by the year. Each language is a feature and a given respondent may use more than one language. The data looks like this -

```
id | year | java | c++ | python
-------------------------------
0  | 2011 | 0    | 1   | 0
1  | 2011 | 1    | 1   | 0
…
15 | 2012 | 1    | 1   | 0
16 | 2012 | 1    | 0   | 1
…
300| 2015 | 0    | 0   | 1
…
```

Now we could have 100 rows for 2011, 500 rows for 2012, 1000 rows for 2015 and so on. I want to compare the popularity of the languages being used year on year. I can't do a simple countplot as the bars for a given language may be smaller in 2011 and very large in 2015. However I want to have that bars that show that 5% of the same in 2011 use python, where by 2015 we see 45% use python.

I've tried to aggregate the data by means after grouping by the year. This gives me the data that I need, but I am unable to come up with a good visualization.

I could melt (would that be right?) all the data into one single column called 'language', however I will lose the ability to calculate / plot the percentage occurrence of each language in a given year.

```py
df_tech = df.groupby('year').agg(['mean'])
df_tech.columns = df_tech.columns.get_level_values(0)
```

```
year | java | c++ | python
--------------------------
2011 | .342 | .432| .133
2012 | .43  | .48 | .211
...
2015 | .534 | .373| .622
...
```

I've been failing at plotting each feature in its own bar on the x axis. I've tried countplot, barplot etc, but I am unable to get multiple features to show up.

Ideally I want to end up with a plot that has each language along the x-axis and for each year, I would like to see a bar per year.

Answer (score 1):

## Set `year` as `index`:

### Data:

```py
 year    java    c++    python
  2011   0.342  0.432    0.133
  2012   0.430  0.480    0.211
  2015   0.534  0.373    0.622

df.set_index('year', inplace=True)

       java    c++  python
year                      
2011  0.342  0.432   0.133
2012  0.430  0.480   0.211
2015  0.534  0.373   0.622
```

#### Seaborn:

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot(data=df)
```

[image]

#### `df.plot()`:

```py
df.plot()
```

[image]

### Barplots:

- Stacked bars are possible and people use them, but they are a poor way to present data because it's difficult for the human eye to ascertain the relative proportion of each category.
- The point of a plot is to unambiguously present the data, which can be done better with plots other than stacked bars.

```py
df.plot.bar()
```

[image]

### With `seaborn.barplot`:

- This requires reshaping the dataframe to a **tidy** format, as follows

```py
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars='year', var_name='lang', value_name='usage')
sns.barplot(x='year', y='usage', data=df_melt, hue='lang')
```

[image]

### FacetGrid:

```py
order = df_melt.lang.unique()
g = sns.FacetGrid(df_melt, col='year', hue='lang', col_wrap=2)
g = g.map(sns.barplot, 'lang', 'usage', order=order)
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. Thanks to you and @ansev for the answers.

I didn't realize that we could achieve this if I melted the aggregated data. All this while I was trying to melt the original data. This (melt) and choosing the rights indexes seems to be the 
key skill in building good visualizations, Rather than this answer itself, the approach that you have demonstrated is super valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Using this dataframe:

```
print(df)
   year   java    c++  python
0  2011  0.342  0.432   0.133
1  2012  0.430  0.480   0.211
2  2015  0.534  0.373   0.622
```

---

[DataFrame.set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```
#%matplotlib inline #only if jupyternotebook
df.set_index('year').plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

[image]

---

you can also plot it as a temporary function:

```
#%matplotlib inline #only if jupyternotebook
df.set_index('year').plot(figsize=(10,10))
```

---

[image]